# Codeigniter. FTP download files

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't download file from ftp.
I want to download javascript file (3.js) from Root folder of FTP

```
        $this->load->library('ftp');
        $config['hostname'] = 'xxx.xx.x.x';
        $config['port'] = 'xxx';
        $config['username'] = 'ftpuser';
        $config['password'] = '123456';
        $config['debug'] = TRUE;
        $this->ftp->connect($config);
        $this->ftp->download("/3.js", "http://test.net/public_html/js/3.js");
```

But I have this Error

> FTP download Unable to download the specified file. Please check your path

Then I will try this method

```
$files = $this->ftp->list_files('');

        foreach($files as $file)
        {
            $this->ftp->download($file, "http://test.net/public_html/js/".basename($file));
        }
```

But error will happend

Please help me!

Comment: You need to save the file to a path on your server.  That means you need to use the correct path, not the URL.  eg. `$this->ftp->download("/3.js", "/var/www/public_html/js/3.js");`

Answer (score 2):

`$this->ftp->download("/3.js", "http://test.net/public_html/js/3.js");`

should probably be

`$this->ftp->download("/home/remoteacct/3.js", "/home/localacct/public_html/js/3.js", "ascii");`

Your asking the ftp server to send you the file: '/3.js' which isn't a specific enough path. You are also asking codeigniter to store the file via http instead of via the filesystem. Add the full server path to the file you are downloading and change the web path to a server path.

Change 'remoteacct' and 'localacct' to match your specific directory information